# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException when calling SerialDevice.FromIdAsync

Tags: exception, uwp, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I'm making a simple helper class for accessing my barcode scanner. I can do it using SerialPort constructor like:

```
new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

But I want my class to autodetect propper port name, so I first find the DeviceInformation:

```
var all = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();

var foundBarcode = all.First(device => device.Name.ToLower().Contains("barcode"));
```

Then I try to get It like this:

```
var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(foundBarcode.Id);
```

But when I do so I get 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll.

How can I fix it?

PS.
I have serial communication capability in my manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, appearently

```
DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
```

returns items with different ids than

```
string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var all = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

Now it works, I guess when first approach adds some USB identificator for emulated COMs.